# Which file does my script pick first when moving a file?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps script that moves a Google Drive file to another Google Drive map. This happens every 4 hours because of a time-based trigger. Does anyone know which file it chooses to move? The files have a random name so should be moved randomly. However, it seems the scripts only moves the last uploaded files.

For context: I use the script in combination with IFTTT for [this Twitter account](https://twitter.com/RandomFootyPics).

```
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("SourceFolderId").getFiles();
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("TargetFolderId");
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getFolderById("SourceFolderId");
    pull.removeFile(file);

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function moveRandomly(s,t) {
  var files=DriveApp.getFolderById(s).getFiles();
  var fA=[];
  while(files.hasNext()){fA.push(files.next().getId());}
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fA[Math.floor(Math.random()*fA.length)]);
  var destination=DriveApp.getFolderById(t);
  destination.addFile(file);
  var pull=DriveApp.getFolderById("SourceFolderId");
  pull.removeFile(file);
}
```